# CanvasJS Column chart with external json data not loading

Tags: canvasjs

Im trying to load this column chart with external data in Json format from a file

I have a jsfiddle with what i have so far.
Thanks for any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/t9n4d8z4/1/

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var dataPoints = [];
          $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1kfs1", function(result) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
              dataPoints.push({
                label: result[i].label,
                y: parseInt(result[i].y)
              });
            }
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
              data: [{
                type: "column",
                dataPoints: result
              }]
            });

            chart.render();
          });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

json format was not handled properly.

Here is the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/t9n4d8z4/3/

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var dataPoints = [];
          $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1kfs1", function(result) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= result.dataPoints.length - 1; i++) {
              dataPoints.push({
                label: result.dataPoints[i].label,
                y: parseInt(result.dataPoints[i].y)
              });
            }

            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
              data: [{
                type: "column",
                dataPoints: dataPoints
              }]
            });

            chart.render();
          });
        });
```

```html
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
```